# TDD, IO, File, Java. Как сделать тесты для чтения файла?

Tags: java, io, test-driven-development

Мне надо протестировать такой метод:

```
// метод для просмотра содержания каталога
static void seeCatalog(File catalog) {
    if (catalog.isDirectory()) {
        String[] list = catalog.list();
        for (String item : (list != null ? list : new String[0])) {
            if (new File(format("%s/%s", path, item)).isDirectory()) {
                System.out.println(format("%s%s", item, "/"));
            } else {
                System.out.println(item);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Начал писать тест:

```
    @Test
    public void whenThen() {
        File file = new File(???ВОТ ТУТ ПРОБЛЕМА???)
        ViewFileSystem.seeCatalog(file);

    }
```

И тут встал вопрос: а какой мне путь указывать? Что я не укажу как абсолютный путь на другом компе будет другое.

Как мне корректно протестировать этот метод? Помогите пожалуйста. Может пример небольшой кто предложит а то что-то никак не пойму что делать тут...

Comment: Как вариант, можно создать файл во временной директории перед тестом и после теста удалить его.

Comment: Хорошая мысль только вот где его создавать так что-бы и на линуксоидах и на винде работало?

Comment: Можно создавать файл во временной директории: `File.createTempFile("tmp", ".tmp")`   
или директорию: `Files.createTempDirectory(null).toFile()`

Comment: И где она создастся если я напишу Files.createTempDirectory(null).toFile() ???

Comment: из Javadoc: "Creates a new directory in the default temporary-file directory, using the given prefix to generate its name. The resulting Path is associated with the default FileSystem."  

Для разных ОС, это разная директория. Для Windows 7 - %TEMP%.
Для Linux - $TMPDIR

Comment: Ну тогда это не решает мою проблему если бы я мог сделать проверку на то какая система запускает то мог бы создавать папку в корне: C:// или просто / для линуксов.

Comment: Почему не решает? В windows/linux существует temporary-file directory, к которой пользователь имеет доступ и в которой можно создать файл/директорию. И вам не надо самостоятельно делать никаких больше проверок. Это универсальный прием и будет работать независимо от системы или пользователя.

Comment: Я чувствую что вы говорите что-то умное но не могу понять что, не знаю этих классов. А можете кусочек кода набросать что-бы мне понять как это делается?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49643/discussion-between-sergi-and-).

Comment: Вам нужно использовать моки и/или virtual file system. https://github.com/google/jimfs https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-vfs/ http://site.mockito.org/

Comment: Моки, конечно хорошо, но зачем усложнять?

Comment: @Sergi чтобы тесты не выполнялись со скоростью I/O и не проваливались по мановению заполненной файловой системой.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно создать файл во временной директории перед тестом и после теста удалить его. Создать можно, например, так: `Files.createTempDirectory(null).toFile()`
Это должно работать на любой системе одинаково.

Comment: На самом деле, в JUnit есть специальный [TestRule](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/rules/TestRule.html) для этого дела - [TemporaryFolder](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/rules/TemporaryFolder.html), который удаляет тестовые папки/файлы по завершении теста

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.nio.file.Files;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;

class {
    private static File dir;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void beforeClass() throws IOException {
        dir = Files.createTempDirectory(null).toFile();
    }

}
```

Вот такое классное решение предложил Sergi.

А вот удаление:

```
@AfterClass 
public static void afterClass() throws IOException { 
    if (dir == null) { 
        return; 
    } 
    deleteRecursive(dir); 
    System.out.println(dir.exists()); 
}
```

Comment: Только там еще было удаление этой директории в методе с аннотацией @AfterClass :)

Comment: А е мое а удалить то я и забыл!